# Moving TFS Template between servers

Tags: tfs, migration

We have customized a TFS Template.

We would now like to move this template to a different TFS Server.

What is the best ways to do this?

Thanks

Shiraz

**EDIT**

We tried the process template as recommend below, but got the following error when trying to import:

```
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2009-11-25 10:28:24Z
Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30162: Task "SharePointPortal" from Group "Portal" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: TF30272: Template not found on the server
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.VerifySiteTemplate(ProjectCreationContext context, String template, Int32 lcid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.ValidateSite(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode site)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.Validate(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskValidator.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
--- end Exception entry ---

2009-11-25 10:28:24Z | Module: Engine | Thread: 7 | TF30202: Task "" from Group "" will not be run because a prior task failed.
2009-11-25 10:28:24Z | Module: Engine | Thread: 7 | TF30202: Task "Site" from Group "Reporting" will not be run because a prior task failed.
2009-11-25 10:28:24Z | Module: Engine | Thread: 7 | TF30202: Task "Populate Reports" from Group "Reporting" will not be run because a prior task failed.
2009-11-25 10:28:24Z | Module: Engine | Thread: 7 | TF30202: Task "" from Group "" will not be run because a prior task failed.
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2009-11-25 10:28:24Z
Module: Template Importer
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ValidationFailedException
Exception Message: TF30175: Process template validation failed
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.EngineStarter.ValidateTemplate(DirectoryInfo templateDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TemplateManagementService.ValidateMethodology(String folderPath, ILogHandler logHandler)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TemplateManagementService.Import(String folderPath, ILogHandler logHandler)
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Type: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TaskFailedException
Exception Message: TF30162: Task "SharePointPortal" from Group "Portal" failed
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.PerformAllTasks(ITaskPerformer taskPerformer, ProjectCreationContext creationContext, List`1 projectTasks)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.EngineStarter.RunEngine(Boolean isValidationRun, String templateFolder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.EngineStarter.ValidateTemplate(DirectoryInfo templateDirectory)
-- end Inner Exception --
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: TF30272: Template not found on the server
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.VerifySiteTemplate(ProjectCreationContext context, String template, Int32 lcid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.ValidateSite(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode site)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.Validate(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskValidator.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
-- end Inner Exception --
--- end Exception entry ---
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Process Template Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181510(VS.80).aspx) to download and upload templates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we tried it but got an error message. I have updated the question.